# ArgumentOutOfException error displaying on occasion

Tags: c#, multithreading

The C# program below is a stock application that models the ups and downs of a stock. I understand the ArgumentOutOfException is thrown when an index is outside of the range of the for loop. However, after rerunning the program multiple times, I noticed that this exception is only thrown on occasion. After running this program 10 times, the exception was thrown 1-4 times at the line

```
stocks.remove(stocks[i]).
```

Looking at my program, is the thread synchronization portion of it causing the problem? If not, what is causing the exception to be thrown on occasion, rather than not at all or every time it's run?

Stock.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab3
{
    //delegate to display stock information
    public delegate void StockNotification(String stockName, double currentValue, double initialV, int stockquantity);

public class Stock
{
    public System.Object lockThis = new System.Object(); //lock each stock object for raising and invoking event
    private String name; 
    private double initValue; //starting or initial value
    private int stkAmt;
    private double current; //curent stock value
    private int numChanges; //number of times stock value changes
    private int maxChange; //the range within a stock can change every time unit
    private double notifyThreshold; //the threshold at which collection of customers for a stock are notified
    static string[] operations = { "+", "-" }; //array of operations to change stock value (+ or -)

    Thread thr; //thread object

    /*default constructor*/
    public Stock() { }

    /*constructor w/ given parameter values*/
    public Stock(String stkName, int starting, int amt, int max, int thresh)
    {
        name = stkName;
        initValue = starting;
        current = initValue;
        stkAmt = amt;
        maxChange = max;
        notifyThreshold = thresh;
        thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Activate));
        thr.Start(); //start thread
    }

    /*property that controls the variable stockAmt*/
    public int StockQuantity
    {
        get { return stkAmt; }
        set { stkAmt = value; }
    }

    /*read-only property that gets name of stock*/
    public string StockName
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    /*changes stock value after a period of time 
     end method when # of changes to stock value match 
     stock quantity*/
    public void Activate()
    {          
        numChanges = 0;
        for (; ; )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            ChangeStockValue();
            if (numChanges == stkAmt)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    /*change stock value - add number between 1 and some specified number
     raise event if difference between current and starting values exceed threshold*/
    public void ChangeStockValue()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int oper = rnd.Next(operations.Length);
        if(oper == 0) //add random number to current stock value
        {
            current += rnd.Next(10, maxChange); 
        }
        else if(oper == 1) //subtract random number from current stock value
        {
            current -= rnd.Next(10, maxChange);
        }
        numChanges++;
        if (numChanges == stkAmt) //# of times stock values changes matches stock's quantity
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            double gainRounded = Math.Round(((current - initValue) / initValue) * 100,2); //get stock gain/loss

            //stock gain/loss is outside stock's threshold range (ex: -5% to 20% w/ 20 being threshold)
            if (gainRounded > this.notifyThreshold || gainRounded < this.notifyThreshold * -1)
            {
                lock(lockThis) //raise stock event 1 stock obj at a time
                {
                    RaiseEvent(); //send data to StockEventData object; send object attributes to listener
                }                  
            }
        }
    }

    /*this method sends stock information to the event listener
     event type StockNotification is invoked*/
    protected virtual void RaiseEvent()
    {
        StockEventData stock = new StockEventData();
        stock.stkName = name;
        stock.currentVal = current;
        stock.initialVal = initValue;
        stock.quantityStk = stkAmt;            
        StockEvent?.Invoke(stock.stkName, stock.currentVal, stock.initialVal, stock.quantityStk);
    }       
    public event StockNotification StockEvent; //event of type StockNotification               
}

/*this class brings stock data to the event listener*/
public class StockEventData : EventArgs
{
    public String stkName { get; set; }
    public double currentVal { get; set; }
    public double initialVal { get; set; }
    public int quantityStk { get; set; }
}   
}
```

StockCustomer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab3
{
    public class StockCustomer
    {
        private String customer;
        private List<Stock> stocks;
        private readonly System.Object lock1 = new System.Object(); //lock object for displaying stock info in file
        private double gainThreshold; //customer's personal threshold

    /*default constructor*/
    public StockCustomer(String name, double gainLimit)
    {
        customer = name;
        gainThreshold = gainLimit;
        stocks = new List<Stock>();
    }

    /*add stock to a list
     @param s - stock object*/
    public void AddStock(Stock s)
    {
        stocks.Add(s);
        s.StockEvent += Notify; //add stock to the event handler
    }

    /*event handler that displays stock information in console and file
     @param stkName - stock name
     @param currentVal - current stock value
     @param initVal - initial stock value
     @param quantityStk - stock quantity*/
    private void Notify(string stkName, double currentVal, double initVal, int stockQuantity)
    {
        string net = ""; //string that will contain either gain or loss text
        double gainOrLoss = Math.Round(((currentVal - initVal) / initVal) * 100.00, 2); //get stock value

        //if stock gain is outisde range of customer's threshold, sell the stock
        if (gainOrLoss > gainThreshold || gainOrLoss < gainThreshold*-1)
        {
            if(gainOrLoss < gainThreshold * -1) //customer's stock value is a loss
            {
                gainOrLoss *= -1;
                net = "% loss";
            }
            else //customer's stock value is a gain
            {
                net = "% gain";
            }

            //remove stock from list after displaying in console and file
            for (int i = 0; i < stocks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (stocks[i].StockName == stkName)
                {
                    //display stock info to console
                    Console.WriteLine(this.customer.PadRight(12) + stkName.PadRight(12) + initVal.ToString().PadRight(5) +
               currentVal.ToString().PadRight(7) + gainOrLoss + net);

                    // Create a string array with lines of stock info, current date and time
                    string[] lines = { DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").PadRight(12),
            DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss").PadRight(13),this.customer.PadRight(12),
            stkName.PadRight(12), initVal.ToString().PadRight(5),
            currentVal.ToString().PadRight(7) + gainOrLoss + net};

                    // Set a variable to the My Documents path.
                    string mydocpath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                    mydocpath1 = Path.Combine(mydocpath1, "WriteLines.txt");                       

                    lock (lock1) //1 stock object displayed in file; repeats for other stock objects
                    {
                        //create a stream for a file
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(mydocpath1, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            // Write the string array to a new file named "WriteLines.txt".                
                            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fs))
                            {                                   
                                foreach (string line in lines)
                                {
                                    outputFile.Write(line); //write stock info to file
                                }
                                outputFile.WriteLine("");
                                outputFile.Close();
                                outputFile.Dispose();

                            }
                            fs.Close();
                            fs.Dispose();
                        }                           
                    }
                    stocks.Remove(stocks[i]);
                }
            }
        }                        
    }
}
}
```

Program.cs (main method)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab3
{    

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        Stock stock1 = new Stock("Technology", 160, 25, 20, 30);
        Stock stock2 = new Stock("Retail", 140, 20, 10, 15);
        Stock stock3 = new Stock("Banking", 90, 25, 15, 25);
        Stock stock4 = new Stock("Commodity", 500, 30, 20, 22);
        StockCustomer b1 = new StockCustomer("Andrew",28);
        b1.AddStock(stock1);
        b1.AddStock(stock4);
        b1.AddStock(stock3);
        b1.AddStock(stock2);
        StockCustomer b2 = new StockCustomer("Harrison",25);
        b2.AddStock(stock3);
        b2.AddStock(stock4);
        b2.AddStock(stock2);
        b2.AddStock(stock1);
        StockCustomer b3 = new StockCustomer("Jimmy",30);
        b3.AddStock(stock2);
        b3.AddStock(stock1);
        b3.AddStock(stock3);
        b3.AddStock(stock4);           
        Console.ReadKey();
    }       
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is that you are removing items within the loop while iterating "up" the array. Let's say you have 2 items in your array and you remove the first one. On the second pass through the loop, you are going to attempt to access the item at position 1, but the array only has one item in it now at position 0, thus the exception.

The approach that I take in situations like this is to always work backwards through the array:

```
for (int i = stocks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```